# Preventing repetitive data in date fields ActionsScript2

Tags: date, actionscript, field

I have four date fields on a form and I need to alert the user when they have entered repetitive dates. I have already created an array that generates and checks the dates, but throwing the alert is not working for me. This is what I have so far.

```
else if ((dateRow1.text== dateRow2.text) || (dateRow1.text == dateRow3.text) || (dateRow1.text == dateRow4.text)) {
        alert.show("You must have unique dates for each field");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your text fields are all distinct from each other:

```
var t:Array = [dateRow1, dateRow2, dateRow3, dateRow4];
var l:Number = t.length;
var i:Number;
var j:Number;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var ti = t[i]; // dateRow1... dateRow4
    for (j in t) {
        if (ti != t[j] && ti.text == t[j].text) trace(ti + "==" + t[j]);
    }
}
```